# What's the quickest way to create a web form using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Java class with over 60 fields that represent different data points I need to get from the user. Since Spring Boot provides such an easy way to map these to a database, I was wondering if it also provides an easy way to map them to a web form? Essentially just generating the 60+ text boxes for me so that I only have to do the styling and validation rules?

It would certainly save a lot of effort. Does this solution exist, what is it called?

Answer (score 1):

There are some IDE tools that can kind of do this but probably not what you're actually looking for. You might consider moving your project to [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) or [Grails](https://grails.org/); both of which support some form of scaffolding.